# JqGrid InlineEdit With editUrl: 'clientArray' Can Not Save

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to edit grid data and save it to the grid itself for later posting.

But i get a javascript error in `jquery1.4.2.min.js` saying "**Invalid Argument**" at the following location when ever i hit Enter after Editing the row to save.

```
if(x){e.username?x.open(n,e.url,e.async,e.username,e.password):x.open(n,e.url,e.async);
```

I am using Asp.net MVC2 with VS2008

here is my JS

```
$(function() {
    pageloadButtons();
    $('.auto').autoNumeric();
    var lastsel2;
    // $('.alphanumerich').lettersonly();
    jQuery('#jgrid').jqGrid({
        autowidth: true,
        altRows: true,
        altclass: 'grdAltRwClr',
        datatype: 'xml',
        forceFit: true,
        gridview: true,
        mtype: 'post',
        height: 190,
        rowNum: 0,
        postData: { offid: function() { return $('#p_offid').val(); },
            calendarid: function() { return $('#p_calendarid').val(); }
        },
        url: window.rootPath + 'AttBulkEntry/JGridData',
        editUrl: 'clientArray',
        cellSubmit: 'clientArray',
        beforeSelectRow: function() { return true; },
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if (id && id !== lastsel2) {
            jQuery("#jgrid").saveRow(lastsel2, false, 'clientArray');
                //jQuery('#jgrid').jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel2, function() { alert('saved'); }, 'clientArray');
                jQuery('#jgrid').editRow(id, true);
                lastsel2 = id;
            }
        },
        gridComplete: function() {
            GridComplete();
        },
        colModel: [
              { name: 'act', label: 'View', resizable: false, search: false, sortable: false, title: false, width: 6, index: 'act' }
            , { name: 'attndid', label: 'Attendance ID', width: 15, index: 'attndid' }
            , { name: 'emphistid', label: 'Emp.Hist.ID', width: 22, index: 'emphistid' }
            , { name: 'ename', label: 'Employee Name', width: 20, index: 'ename' }
            , { name: 'paymonth', label: 'Pay Month', width: 12, index: 'paymonth' }
            , { name: 'absent', label: 'Absence', width: 10, index: 'absent', editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
            , { name: 'sanctioned', label: 'Sanctioned', width: 15, index: 'sanctioned', editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
            , { name: 'EL', label: 'EL', width: 5, index: 'EL', editable: true, edittype: 'text' }

            ]

    });


});
```

am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct name of the "editUrl" parameter: `editurl`.

Comment: @Deb: You are welcome! I find it would be nice to implement validation of jqGrid parameters. There are no real naming standards currently in jqGrid and one can find option names like `cellEdit` or `gridview` `ignoreCase`, `datatype` or even as `ExpandColClick`. In the situation such typing error like youth isn't so seldom.